# Linq syntax issue - List.Find(Predicate <T> match)

Tags: linq, list, predicate

I am trying to add some logic in this. But I am not sure how to add a second condition…

**For instance:**

```
        foreach (FolderAssetInfo e in folderAssetsList)
        {
            var foundAsset = databaseAssetsList.Find(a => a.AssetFullName == e.AssetFullName);
            //I want to add an AND logic inside the parenthesis such as:
            //a => a.AssetFullName == e.AssetFullName && a.AssetFirstName == e.AssetFirstName)

            if (foundAsset != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Found it!);
            }
        }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Firstly, `List.Find` *isn't* LINQ. Secondly, the code you've given should work fine - what happened when you tried it?

Comment: The code you have commented out looks correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is perfect:

```
var foundAsset = databaseAssetsList.Find(a => a.AssetFullName == e.AssetFullName && a.AssetFirstName == e.AssetFirstName);
```

Basically, the `Predicate<T>` is just syntax that will return a boolean value.  Your syntax in the comment (`a.AssetFullName == e.AssetFullName && a.AssetFirstName == e.AssetFirstName`) will return a boolean, as written, so it will work fine for the predicate.

---

The one place where you do have a syntax error is your call to `Console.WriteLine` - this will require you to add quotation marks:

```
Console.WriteLine("Found it!"); // Quotes are required here!
```

Comment: The sintaxe was correct after all. I had an extra "=>" by acident. It was giving me "invalid expression" . Thank you all.